# what does ~* mean in an nginx server block

Tags: nginx

as question, I've got a server rewrite in front of me that's using ~* to do something with a domain name, I'm not sure if it's including or excluding.

Thanks

Comment: if ($host ~* example.com)

Comment: hwnd you've not put that as an answer; I can't upvote you?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~*` indicates the location block will be interpreted as a case-insensitive regex match ...